# Emulate/polyfill history.pushstate() in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

`history.pushstate()` is not supported in IE. Is there another way to achieve this in IE?

Comment: Why do you need `pushState()`? Your web-site should be usable **without** `pushState()`, and even without javascript. IE10 supports `pushState()`.

Comment: @SeanHogan a web site without Javascript? You living in 1994?

Comment: I agree with @SeanHogan to a certain degree. A website shouldn't be full-featured without javascript, but should be navigable and usable. What if a script or library fails to load? The webpage should still be usable, even if not entirely functional.

Comment: @Prusprus: Thanks for expanding my comment, although I don't see how anyone can confuse "usable without pushState / javascript" for "must not use javascript". Skim-reading I guess.

Answer (score 28):

Consider using or adapting [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) from GitHub. As per the description:

> History.js gracefully supports the
>   HTML5 History/State APIs (pushState,
>   replaceState, onPopState) in all
>   browsers. Including continued support
>   for data, titles, replaceState.
>   Supports jQuery, MooTools and
>   Prototype. For HTML5 browsers this
>   means that you can modify the URL
>   directly, without needing to use
>   hashes anymore. For HTML4 browsers it
>   will revert back to using the old
>   onhashchange functionality.

IE (upto and including 9), does not support pushstate(). IE 10 supports it.

http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate

Answer (score 17):

Consider using history API for unsupported browsers or see library on https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API

This Javascript library provides an emulation of HTML5 History API for older browsers.

The library operates according to W3C specification, adding no new or incompatible methods. The library can be used exactly as described, for example, in Dive Into HTML5 book http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html or in the History API Specification http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#the-history-interface.

Example of using the library in the pure JS context:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="history-2.0.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {

                // function for the reference is processed
                // when you click on the link
                function handlerAnchors() {
                    // keep the link in the browser history
                    history.pushState( null, null, this.href );


                    // here can cause data loading, etc.


                    // do not give a default action
                    return false;
                }

                // looking for all the links
                var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

                // hang on the event, all references in this document
                for( var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++ ) {
                    anchors[ i ].onclick = handlerAnchors;
                }

                // hang on popstate event triggered
                // by pressing back/forward in browser
                window.onpopstate = function( e ) {

                    // we get a normal Location object

                    /*
                    * Note, this is the only difference when using this library,
                    * because the object document.location cannot be overriden, so
                    * library the returns generated "location" object within an
                    * object window.history, so get it out of "history.location".
                    * For browsers supporting "history.pushState" get generated
                    * object "location" with the usual "document.location".
                    */
                    var returnLocation = history.location || document.location;


                    // here can cause data loading, etc.


                    // just post
                    alert( "We returned to the page with a link: " +
                                                         returnLocation.href );
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/mylink.html">My Link</a>
        <a href="/otherlink.html">Other Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example of using the library along with JQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="history-2.0.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                // looking for all the links and hang on the event,
                // all references in this document
                $("a").click(function() {
                    // keep the link in the browser history
                    history.pushState( null, null, this.href );


                    // here can cause data loading, etc.


                    // do not give a default action
                    return false;
                });

                // hang on popstate event triggered
                // by pressing back/forward in browser
                $( window ).bind( "popstate", function( e ) {

                    // we get a normal Location object

                    /*
                    * Note, this is the only difference when using this library,
                    * because the object document.location cannot be overriden, so
                    * library the returns generated "location" object within an
                    * object window.history, so get it out of "history.location".
                    * For browsers supporting "history.pushState" get generated
                    * object "location" with the usual "document.location".
                    */
                    var returnLocation = history.location || document.location;


                    // here can cause data loading, etc.


                    // just post
                    alert( "We returned to the page with a link: " +
                                                        returnLocation.href );
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/mylink.html">My Link</a>
        <a href="/otherlink.html">Other Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do I get the json object that I push in the state back? So `oncomplete` of an ajax request, I did this `history.pushState({rowAttr: rowAttrHtml, colAttr: colAttrHtml}, null, document.URL);`, then I have `$( window ).bind( 'popstate', function( event ) { var State = history.state; alert(State.data.rowAttr);});`. The alert show `undefined`