# History.js fallback not working properly

Tags: javascript, history.js

I'm using the History.js script https://github.com/browserstate/history.js to record history when using Ajax functions. It works great in modern browsers... however when using something like IE9 it uses the hash fallback but this doesn't actually work as proposed.

E.g. Say my current url is: `http://localhost:8888/Dashboard`

and then I do the following:

`History.replaceState(null, 'Test', 'http://localhost:8888/Test');`

The new url becomes: `http://localhost:8888/Dashboard#./Test200?&_suid=405`

Why is this? Shouldn't it become: `http://localhost:8888/#/Test200?&_suid=405`?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470183/1236238 with the GET-parameter "redirect=true" it will try to hold a normal links. For full information on this library, see file README on archive.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is? As I have implemented a library already... so what exactly is the solution? Thanks for the answer though, much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately Library /balupton/history.js is unable to form a normal link in the older browsers.

Comment: Okies so what do I need to do to fix this? As I don't understand what I'm looking for in that link you posted. Thanks again.

Comment: What you need to do to fix it in the library /balupton/history.js I can not say. Because it is someone else's library, and I'm over it is not subservient, as there is no documented features that would fix it. Library https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API, can be configured for such purposes. Connect it with GET-parameters:
    `history-2.0.3.js?redirect=true&basepath=/&type=/`