# How can I detect the back/forwards buttons being clicked when using History.js?

Tags: jquery, history.js

Im using History.js ([click](https://github.com/balupton/history.js)) with jQuery in my code.

When loading new content via ajax i use:

```
History.pushState({my:stateobject},"newtitle","supernewurl");
```

This seems to work since the URL is updated in the browser.

However, I don't get it where I can hook up my code whenever a back or forward button is pressed. Which method/event is used for this?

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632483/pushstate-and-popstate-manipulating-browsers-history

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to bind an event handler to the `statechange` event, like this:

```
$(window).bind('statechange',function(){
// Do something, inspect History.getState() to decide what
})
```

There is a complete javascript snippet that comes with History.js, which can be used to 'ajaxify' a site completely: https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify

Take a look there for more inspiration.

Comment: why was this downvoted? this is the correct thing to do...although I would probably do something like:

`History.Adapter.bind(window,'popstate',function(){
        $modalContext.modal('close');
      });`

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn't capture the *back click event*, as there is none.

What you want to do is make sure the `history` object is in the right state by using `window.history.pushState`,  `window.history.popState`, `window.history.replaceState` methods.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use the "onPopState" event to trigger my custom AJAX code.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  $(fellowModal).foundation('reveal', 'close');
};
```

I tried several other things and that is what worked for me.