# How can I detect if the user is refreshing the page or has arrived from an internal link?

Tags: javascript, http-headers

I have a [Toast Message](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-toast-messages/0.1) that has some useful information when someone reaches a page. But it's set up that even when I refresh it shows up.

How can I make it so that it only appears when you arrived on the page from a link-click and not from a page refresh? Is this possible? Would differentiating between a 200 and a 304 on some site-wide resource work?

Comment: If you are wanting to use client-side script to do this your going to need to set a flag in a cookie or if outdated browsers are not supported use localStorage.

Comment: @SimonStaton if that's the best way. How would I do that?

Comment: You have to try it yourself first ;) http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: This also looks like a good place to check: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27778749/1075247