# Page navigation and update url with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

first of all, i'd like to say i'm still learning ajax/jquery so, sorry if any stupid mistake.

Ok, so, i was looking all around the internet to try to find a solution to what i'm trying to do. I found something here, something there but i'm struggling to put everything together. Here we go.

---

#### Objective

I want to create a website using ajax navigation. When i click on a menu, only the `content` div will update. Also i want the `url` to update, so if any user want to share that page, it will be possible. Also the possibility to go back and forward (this i think will be automatic added when using the url update).

---

#### What i have

I did the website and already have the ajax navigation. I also i have a `active` link working. The navigation is working fine. This is the code i'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var content = $('#site'),
        firstLink = $(".navbar li:first-child a"),
        firstLoad = firstLink.attr("href"),
        navLink = $(".navbar li a");
    content.load(firstLoad); //default load
    navLink.on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        content.load(this.href, function () {
            FB.XFBML.parse(); //update facebook page plugin in each page laod
        });
    });
});
```

And this is my navigation bar:

```
[...rest of code...]
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="content/home.php">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/servicos.php">Serviços</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/advogados.php">Advogados</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/escritorio.php">Escritório</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/noticias.php">Notícias</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/contato.php">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="site"></div>
[...rest of code...]
```

---

#### The Problem

At the momment, i have 2 main problems, which are:

1. Update the URL;
2. When share a link, it loads only the content;

1- I was trying to use `history.js` to do it and kind of did. But everytime i click on a link, it will duplicate the code. For example, i have a url `site.com/content/home.php` and i click on the contact page, the url will be: `site.com/content/content/contact.php` and next will be `site.com/content/content/content/about.php`and so on..

2- When i was trying the `URL update` i tried to share a link, for example, `site.com/content/about.php` but when i opened the new page i only got the `about` part of code. No header, menu, footer and other things.

---

#### What i tried

I was looking [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632483/pushstate-and-popstate-manipulating-browsers-history) and got the same problems i had before. Even with the modifications.

This is the jquery code i was using when following that topic:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var content = $('#site'),
        firstLink = $(".navbar li:first-child a"),
        firstLoad = firstLink.attr("href"),
        navLink = $(".navbar li a");

    content.load(firstLoad); //default load

    navLink.on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var newLink = $(this).attr("href");

         History.pushState(null, newLink, newLink);

        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        content.load(newLink, function () {
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        });

    });

    History.Adapter.bind(window, "statechange", function() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $("a[href='" + History.getState().title + "']").addClass("active");
        content.load(document.location.href); 
    });
});
```

---

So, does anyone knows what i'm doing wrong? Is there a best way to achieve what i want? Or how to do it?

Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your hrefs are relative urls.
Put "/" before "content"!

```html
[...rest of code...]
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="/content/home.php">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="/content/servicos.php">Serviços</a></li>
            <li><a href="/content/advogados.php">Advogados</a></li>
            <li><a href="/content/escritorio.php">Escritório</a></li>
            <li><a href="/content/noticias.php">Notícias</a></li>
            <li><a href="/content/contato.php">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="site"></div>
[...rest of code...]
```

Comment: almost there.. It's replacing everything after `.com` so if i have some page located in other folder, it will replace everything and it will not work. Also, if i copy the link to share with someone, it doesn't load properly. It only loads the portion of that specific page.