# Is there alternative of html5 api history.pushState?

Tags: javascript, html

From [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history), the "history.pushState()" of Html5 Api cannot use on android browser < 4.2.

Is there alternative?

please let me know..
thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emulate/polyfill history.pushstate() in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622449/emulate-polyfill-history-pushstate-in-ie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before `pushState` came along, people used the fragment identifier of the URL (`location.hash`). Libraries exist that will give a common interface between using that and the history API.

Using a fragment id doesn't fallback to URLs that can be processed server side though, so I'd just fallback to the non-JS version on those devices. (Possibly adding a small recommendation to change browser).

Comment: You are awesome and you should feel awesome.