# How to get an image to not vanish even when the page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this button, and when its clicked an image is shown, but if the page is refreshed the image disappears, and I don't want that. How do i get the image to stay even when the page refreshes.

here is my image show function:

```
<script>

function showImage()
 {
$("#loadingImage").show();      
 };

</script>
```

and here is my button:

```
<input name="Failure Analysis Lab"  style="white-space:normal;"    
onclick="moveText(this.name);showImage();form1.submit() " 
style="width: 272px; height: 30px;" type="button" 
value="7QKD Failure Analysis Lab" />
```

Comment: What do you mean get the image to stay?  You mean you want it to stay displayed?  You can use a cookie for this.

Comment: How exactly would i do that?

Comment: or even just pass a parameter

Comment: Google "jquery cookies" to find jQuery plugins that can set and read cookies. Then have your `document.ready` function check the cookie and call `showImage()` if the cookie is set.

Comment: *Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding** of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work,** and the expected results.*

Comment: Here foobar, let me help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sessionStorage` for this.

In your init:

```
var isImage = sessionStorage.getItem('isImage');

if (isImage !== null) showImage();

function showImage() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('isImage', '1');
    $("#loadingImage").show();      
};
```

If the image has been shown a value is stored in the temporary storage (will be erased when browser is closed -  if you want it to be permanent use `localStorage` instead. [Support goes back to IE8](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage)). Then on refresh the value is checked for and if exists the image will be shown.

Comment: @foobar2023 be aware that leaving the page and following links to come back to it later in the same session will also make the image immediately visible, unless you clear the 'isImage' from sessionStorage. Maybe you want that, maybe not.

Comment: I have multiple showImage functions, and I am getting an error that the last clicked image is the image that shows for all. And by that i mean this: let says I click button 6 that image stays also for when i click button 5, 4, 3 ,2 1, and so on. How do i fix that?

Comment: @foobar2023 you can store an ID for each image on the `setItem` (instead of "1"). Then check if that value exists instead of `null`. Like `var isImage3 = sessionStorage.getItem('3'); ...`

Comment: This is what I have:        'var isImage = sessionStorage.getItem('1');
    
    
    function showImage() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('isImage', '1');
    $("#loadingImage").show();
        }'
       
and now it doesn't show on when the page refreshes

Comment: @foobar2023 it's a bit put of scope for the original question IMO. I'll suggest you open a new question and show more of this code there and then we can take a look at this problem.

Comment: here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869065/cant-get-sessionstorage-to-work-correctly) to the new question

Answer (score 2):

[You can set and get a cookie like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery) on your button click:

```
$.cookie("showImage", true);
```

Then do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var image = $('#loadingImage');
    if($.cookie('showImage') {
        image.addClass('image-visible');
    } else {
        image.show();
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.image-visible {display: block}
```

Comment: When I try this it says I cant have $.cookie("showImage", true); within my onclick

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history.pushState()` to add a hash or a parameter to the current page. When the page loads or reloads you can check for the presence and show the image initially

```js
var hstate = {}; // state object you may or may not want to use
history.pushState( hstate, 'Page Title', '#img' );
// -- or --
history.pushState( hstate, 'Page Title', '?img=true' );
```

If needed you can get the current URL first so you can preserve existing parameters or hashes when you add your own.

To support older browsers use a polyfill such as [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js), as mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622449/).